Why am I getting "Permission denied" errors when Git Bash tries to create symbolic links and copy files in the /etc/ directory on Windows?
The Git Bash CLI is failing to create symbolic links and copy files to system directories (/etc/) due to permission being denied on multiple files and directories when launched on Windows.
How to fix this error?
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/mtab': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' -> '/etc/hosts'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/hosts': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\protocol' -> '/etc/protocols'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/protocols': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services' -> '/etc/services'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/services': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\networks' -> '/etc/networks'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/networks': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/01-devices.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/03-mtab.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/06-windows-files.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/99-post-install-cleanup.post': Permission denied

This is what it looks like in my CLI:

My bash application

Git application

I have tried to run git config --global core.symlinks false  cli, but that doesn't work after all.

Aren't symbolic links on Windows limited to admin accounts?

ln and bash are not a standard windows commands. What else are you using? WSL? MSYS? Something else? What is the full command you tried to run that gave you the above errors?
